# Yii cgridview give reference to checkbox

Tags: yii

Because when adding the CCheckBoxColumn to my vgridview in a form, in return I have no precise index for working with the checked box data's.  So I try to add the 'uncheckValue' but I am unable to link it to the reference value of my table. Is there a way to access this value for the current row ? (the $data->reference in my code return a Undefined variable).

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'gview',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    'client',
    'reference',
    array(
        'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'id'=>'CB',
        'selectableRows'=>2,
        'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array(
            'uncheckValue'=>$data->reference, ),

    )),));
```

Tks anyone could put me on the way (if there is one... )

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do that without rendering the checkbox yourself (a 'raw' `CDataColumn`).

Comment: Tks for information, I'll try to explore the suggested tip. I have also read elsewhere there is an Ajax way for reading checkBox state.

Comment: DCoder solution is better but It was little difficult for me to find the correct syntax of the value for the raw data column it should be :
'\'<input id="tabinputchk" type="checkbox" name="id[\'.$data->reference.\']"/>\''

Answer (score 1):

I finally find one way is to extend CCheckBoxColumn. 
As inside this code I have access to $data. Now my form return checkbox with his 'name' as the 'reference' column of my table, so I can do further batch treatment.
The uncheckValue hidden field was not suitable as it was only giving index for unchecked fields (!).

I believe this code should not stay in view but in extension...
Any comments still welcome....

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CCheckBoxColumn');
class LIndexCheckBoxColumn extends CCheckBoxColumn {

public $linkId; 

public function renderDataCellContent($row,$data)
    {
    if($this->value!==null)
        $value=$this->evaluateExpression($this->value,array('data'=>$data,'row'=>$row));
    else if($this->name!==null)
        $value=CHtml::value($data,$this->name);
    else
        $value=$this->grid->dataProvider->keys[$row];

    $checked = false;
    if($this->checked!==null)
        $checked=$this->evaluateExpression($this->checked,array('data'=>$data,'row'=>$row));

    $options=$this->checkBoxHtmlOptions;
    //$name=$options['name'];
    $varLink=$this->linkId;
    $name=$data->$varLink;
    unset($options['name']);
    $options['value']=$value;
    $options['id']=$this->id.'_'.$row;
    echo CHtml::checkBox($name,$checked,$options);
}

    }

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        'client',
        'reference',
        array(
            'class'=>'LIndexCheckBoxColumn',
            'id'=>'cb',
            'selectableRows'=>2,
            'linkId'=>'reference',
    )),));
```